# Apex Scatter Chart - how to handle overlapping points?

Tags: visualforce-charting

I have a VF page that displays a ScatterSeries chart - where each point is an Account (coordinates are two values on the Account).  The issue is that some of the points have the same coordinates, so they overlap, resulting in some/many of the point being essentially hidden from view.  Is there a standard way to enable the User to see all of the Accounts at a given point?  (I built it so that when you hover over a point, it shows info about the associated Account...but the user can only see the "top" Account (in the z-coordinate sense of the word.))

Thanks so much for your time.
chris

Comment: Try to change the data model so that two point won't overlap.

Comment: Hello Saroj - can you offer any additional guidance?  The data model is pretty simple - there are two scores (integers) on the Account object - one is the x-axis and the other is the y.  I could make sure all coordinates are unique, that means changing the data, which feels like a bad idea.  It seems that the chart should have a mechanism for handling this scenario.  I'm sure I'm not the first person to have this issue - but I'm not finding anything on the forums or documentation.  Thanks.